# Write a Unicode Unpacker

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, unicode

We all know scoring by characters is ripe for abuse. Let's prove this.

### The Challenge

Output the following:

```
"m8V}G=D@7G1lAI,v08`
#(hNb0A8T!g;==SVaG5~
g"jUF!bmRY(3I@na?2S{
fJVzo/GQYU%ybpfUq3aG
Yza[jc,WJ$bP^7r};Da}
V-!Z+Nk:`/poc}d/X:G\
sWX{dbAUv6,i]%RG$hRp
),bd+?/{U1tU[;<;u.Nk
ZFPIOzJ/HimL!nexc,ls
HM%k3D$n2|R,8L?'eI_n
qs.kzbil$UQy_#Z)l#i%
*G4gr2<R^y#/iQ9,<+p%
}BYnb3_&:!m;#~QL1C?t
f.U>wIkTz=P>bf!uwb!d
z()rG)>~:q4#\}~pQEvZ
=OT8T4<i50%/8%eX^"3E
#Ks(8}OzZ&]RQ(-BLy<7
p7B~GEsF$)>?a"dtGCC'
H;:n&p&Z($ukNd,Et.$O
F*Uq0$dm,m%ejPT~u,qL
```

The characters inside the box are selected uniformly at random between the codepoints `0x21` and `0x7e`. This means they should not be compressable much ordinarily. However, in this challenge, your code is scored by the number of *characters*, which can range in codepoint between `0x00` and `0x10ffff`. Since this gives about 21 bits of information per character, and the box contains about 7 bits of information per character, approaching a 3:1 packing should be possible.

Note that:

- As usual, you may output to STDOUT or return the string from a function;
- A trailing newline on the last line is optional. Apart from this, the output must be exactly as given.
- List representations are acceptable if returning from a function.

### Scoring

The score is the length of your code in *characters*, expressed in the encoding of your language's interpreter. For most languages, this will be UTF-8. Note that languages that use an [SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS), such as most golfing languages, are at a huge disadvantage here as the number of characters is equal to the number of bytes.

Note that characters are not the same as grapheme clusters. For example, ‍ is actually 3 characters (`0x1f468 0x200d 0x1f9b2`).

Comment: was CSPRNG used to generate this text, or could it possibly be reversed? If so, is that a loophole?

Comment: @CommandMaster I used a secure random generator.

Comment: What is an interpreter's encoding?  It was my impression that encoding is just used for displaying text, for example in an ide.  While interpreters (and compilers) just look at the raw data.  How do I know what my interpreter's encoding is?

Comment: The text is 420 characters (400 without whitespace)

Comment: If the scoring is in *characters* then why even mention encoding? A character is a character, regardless what encoding is used. Talking about encoding just confuses thing, as some languages accept source code in different encodings.

Comment: @WheatWizard The raw data is just a sequence of bits (or bytes, if you like to group bits together). An encoding maps a sequence of bits to a character. For instance, a bit sequence of `01011101` (`0x5D` as hex bytes) maps to `]` if your encoding is ASCII or UTF-8, but it maps to `)` if your encoding is EBCDIC. And when your encoding is UTF-16,  `01011101` is an incomplete sequence, as each character requires 16 or 32 bits.

Comment: I'm confused. The string which should be outputted contains newlines. But you also say the output consist of random characters between code points 0x21 and 0x7e. Which code chart are you using? ASCII, ISO-LATIN-1 and Unicode all have newlines (LF) at codepoint 0x10. EBCDIC has LF at code point 0x25, but many of the given characters are outside of the 0x21 .. 0x7e range in EBCDIC.

Comment: Perl, on a platform with allows for 128 bit characters, accepts `170141183460469231731687303715884105727` (`2^127 - 1`) different characters, ideal for compression. No idea how you would post such a thing though.

Comment: @Abigail Yes that is how I understand it.  But as I said that is a way of *displaying* a sequence of bytes for human readers.  Which is not a part of the interpreter (or compiler), since computers can't make use of visual output.  I don't see how we can look at an interpreter, an entirely digital apparatus, and say that a particular way of displaying data is "its encoding".

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3, <s>223</s> <s>221</s> <s>216</s> <s>214</s> 212 chars

```python
ጸ=0
for  in"ጸꛯ裶":ጸ=ጸ<<20|ord()
while ጸ:print(end=chr(ጸ%128));ጸ>>=7
```

Converts from base 2²⁰ (1048576) to base 128. Just for fun, I used some of the letters from the encoded string as variable names.

---

**Edit 1**: (221) I saved two characters by using base 128 rather than base 127, allowing me to use the bit-shift operation `>>=7` rather than the integer division `//=127`.

**Edit 2**: (216) Thanks to ovs in the comments for suggesting a way to save a whopping five characters.

**Edit 3**: (214) Using base 2²⁰ allows us to save another two characters, because we can write the constant as `2**20` in the code, which only takes five characters to write rather than seven.

**Edit 4**: (212) We can write `ጸ<<20|ord()` instead of `ጸ*2**20+ord()`.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first answer!

Comment: You can save a few characters by directly printing from the loop with `while ബ:print(end=chr(ബ%128));ബ>>=7`. Have you tried lower bases like 117 or 95? This might be shorter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks @ovs! Not sure why I didn’t think of that.

Comment: I have tried a variety of bases, and this was the shortest overall, but there may be possibilities I’ve overlooked.

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 150 chars

```
⍘↨Ｅ¶涿燁⪆΅㓬萾℅ι×φφ⁺γ¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DdHZjppgFADgZ53MTS@aNOkTAMoyEVxAVBY3EKUgLlCZQX8hmd7PPENt0vaq/c85D2D7vcL3@OHh8@Onh4/3@82Y3JT4L4teS3IPDMeiDPK2gqhvc6czpZ6rw8V1SH564lFPoMFsjnLOOLMZidaBT9IzT9YRpTuV/LoFrfWU5osZjRofa39AWbwg1TnTKvLxWW6TUxUoh22wRAX3bZWio0qFbUC0iqBcOMC0hsJFi7Os4IE@4bmZw6y0sZ8f@MipfpYNmP6JJ1cLwskRhY6EUsDQVRN8Fhq87ERKwiEkWcI3OxGvhf1LFWG9ZlBVJ9BLj5eDEVyMGDaNBqnQ5amfwtK0b4kCrYPIT3GPpOkRgySD9Mq@NztYvnRoJZ3Q87tQqwvIDca9xOFba0ttVcDYzbD0LChriyaDDrwsBnD@mpJmRjQddkkZ5xArOa9rna/YELojmY/SPmmhSEYz4Lah0jJYghur1HK6P6wtil9WkPW2f6Q@ttsRjadfsRcPoXQ1EpQTX14yyKs9esIcZ50zdM0tnw//r2kzvsqvaJwy7JgKxZ6OL/MCwsCniWLSrGJ8v@mAJhb0tKxBswM8ShJesgP39hlNnysMWQtzdsbgOqTYqPgmGP3u17DT9Vtbfqu@jd@Vd@Umnt@K1/J@/wc) No verbose version (but see encoder below); the succinct code that the deverbosifier generates doesn't work and is suboptimal anyway. Note that Charcoal actually defaults to Unicode, so this is the only case where I don't really mean `charcoal -e` (to use SBCS encoding). Explanation:

```
   ...          Long string (including leading newline)
  Ｅ             Map over characters
       ι        Current character
      ℅         Take the ordinal
         φφ     Predefined variable 1,000
        ×       Multiply (i.e. 1,000,000)
 ↨              Decode array using that base
            γ   Printable ASCII
           ⁺    Concatenated with
             ¶  Literal newline
⍘               Encode integer using custom base
                Implicitly print
```

The encoded string was generated using the following program:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＵＴ⭆↨⍘⪫υ¶⁺γ¶×φφ℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5rU6JQAIa/n18hAnaok3hrZcVLaUq4pmhgamaBIJ64iFxsxcW/7tpuX96ZZ@Z5Zt7lWvWXG9U@nT7X2DZSUHS9KHwKfeyakGFSUhSsYYRSmOGBvDFN25B97MAzSWclhP/NR9WDTTUw/s133N1g96tMz900g1KSHQXQ/MYzy9gxArhCqdUXtc431GVo@BAzDMOfTmmHGydC7f62LOTtOxHtctw7IOG6r@XuOJkw@VrtaawKN0dgpj@UDqE5oyksireu2ig8HcCqO443rDCcKvRe81bKtqgKYBqrLx9L9NylNGlR9hP@Xk3A@JqYXfWtyjvrbZaJzk4qwhwEz5ODrt0pux8Iv9IjgVqPPMAgTb9qsAclHyovfJWPsn0LzDqSOIi77AN2eoRr/F4iOwAPj7RVvKfcwp8R4nqNC0N8c8E2yFqxhm1KGe7fyBljk5gGl0LJ9AvV0WJPsnj4E1WvPBokzamrFd8yFcLhyeOwl281QrDKKvVP0ZLjmlTXVkT0qRE6iCHjC0z9WNmWyHly9Ibt3QzUBjInl6r4JkezHG1MFuliG5C/Asglg3iWeR0N4XWzt6@WgVduHoV20KGYekNN66HQal2AB77iZrzMDFKR1ddRO8xSA9C5VLY5SneQQxsfknyM0LYHTtc7@y8) Link is to verbose version of code. I was somewhat lucky that the encoded string uses no Charcoal characters (which would need quoting) and contains no unprintables (not counting newline as an unprintable).

Comment: FYI this compares to 348 bytes using Charcoal's SBCS string compression.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>259</s> <s>253</s> 250 chars

```js
f=
_=>"៘⋷㆐⇸຺⋄⡊ᙫᷢᰃἙ선ᴱꦁ蘀ȤȫὋ㵽᤽熀ᗜ嶼෎ࢥ魱ʼᅵ鍅Ⴅ".replace(/./gu,c=>String.fromCharCode((n=c.codePointAt())%95+32,n/95%95+32,n/9025+32)).replace(/ /g,"\n")
;document.write(`<xmp>${f()}</xmp>`);
```

Explanation: Simply encodes three ASCII characters using one Unicode character. Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Arnauld. Saved 2 bytes by dividing by 9025 instead of by 95 twice. Saved 3 bytes by subtracting 32 in the encoder:

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/\n/g, " ").replace(/.../g, c=>String.fromCodePoint(c.charCodeAt()-32+(c[1].charCodeAt()-32)*95+(c[2].charCodeAt()-32)*95*95));
o.textContent=f(i.value);
```

```html
<textarea rows=20 cols=20 id=i oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value);>
"m8V}G=D@7G1lAI,v08`
#(hNb0A8T!g;==SVaG5~
g"jUF!bmRY(3I@na?2S{
fJVzo/GQYU%ybpfUq3aG
Yza[jc,WJ$bP^7r};Da}
V-!Z+Nk:`/poc}d/X:G\
sWX{dbAUv6,i]%RG$hRp
),bd+?/{U1tU[;<;u.Nk
ZFPIOzJ/HimL!nexc,ls
HM%k3D$n2|R,8L?'eI_n
qs.kzbil$UQy_#Z)l#i%
*G4gr2<R^y#/iQ9,<+p%
}BYnb3_&:!m;#~QL1C?t
f.U>wIkTz=P>bf!uwb!d
z()rG)>~:q4#\}~pQEvZ
=OT8T4<i50%/8%eX^"3E
#Ks(8}OzZ&]RQ(-BLy<7
p7B~GEsF$)>?a"dtGCC'
H;:n&p&Z($ukNd,Et.$O
F*Uq0$dm,m%ejPT~u,qL
</textarea><pre id=o></pre>
```

Comment: It's OK to pass floats to `String.fromCharCode()`, so you can remove both `|0`.

Comment: In Node, you could do `.replace(/./gu,c=>Buffer([(n=c.codePointAt()-32)%95+32,n/95%95+32,n/9025+32]))`.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 152 chars

Converts between base 94 and base 1125000. The highest byte in the program is `0x10cd84`.

```
"읋쵩䉸蠠殓綳"Ç•HтÄ•β94в33+ç20ôJ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc@9ktJgFIDh0vvY1sZxbbwDx7vQGQsri70ByCZADJAlkCUsS35YAkl2v0B@gBCyZEZ6R2/BcdRii3POlx63epuneb9cfPj4@dPpdPaCDq7L25mAPTnGwnGxzFVy/B1f7KVKUFdgZDZXmwUFvkmeMkJ/blMoWU8ThYtBBlYaVnK7wYdBUjWf6aqfoSGxqr0RuatEEJYSv6xFJG5iLLcM5n5AgduArWCTywpwFBWCeIyzdIWpIIPetMDtJsSuErg3WmBM@njr3@J0uKVemZMs7/g0csDcWrB@YJjkS1SLBXUGczIMg6f6BLWsgU5xg0Uh4qMWY8ePUPDY09qnzqXEZXZHnqyjXL8h1h6j7Uswuosr0TZpYYmQewzCaEizuMHHLOP7XovPHkvcJQ/YZCFKSpdvjZDEa/23nPHG6PDPtsEa6jhRYnBqOh16Lm@YbbSXl7z2PFNvbf6Efb5NQ4pHAfYUE0NtRJ1NguKgTrmTUHkzB2dQIxbOcTDb8aWqYHcq0irRKykckxbtQUunfPcw4YX8SF4yRS2XeVFfo/6VcV1QIdfXfzcJDNcarVcS3kYZlVYKi7sO7@ommIt7SK@uaePVwCuv8dDaV9JoeXZs/qpN3/0UjuJzv8dv3/yIz89fHhevXx3T99/2p9N/) For some reason I can't create a working TIO link for this, you will have to paste the code manually.

**Commented**:

```python
"..."                    # long string
        Ç                   # convert to code points
         •HтÄ•β             # convert from base 1125000
               94в          # convert to base 94
                  33+       # add 33 to each digit
                     ç      # convert from code points
                      20ô   # split into groups of 20
                         J  # join each group into a string
                          » # join the groups by newlines
```

The *long string* is generated with [this program](https://tio.run/##HVJtT5JhFP7Or3hmba0UQtBIp1amlbamm7pAJ6WOpi1KSwOttocnBaylTTSnKROe1JwEgrw88rqdC/zQh3v4F@4/Qrdt59M517nOda5z3rwbG59y1GpcDnciyRJsnQoURnSQywFSWVrHUtU8EihRHDJFh7FPMXg6uD84qb9PEa54KDyK6GuWQ5aKLDk08wAydu2OpxTtwOo9rnzm8sl52sDl7bIPPtdtSlHeRSrFrOwMq4j1zFzl/i9cWXR8xCZ8kqDGMjIs4EL8PG3jyhK2uuqncdCvnxA1J1cU/GHpWQpXNcpjBfssNYcSonRwHVEEOw0zlTUWoFMDnXA51NlX9li54n0oZAw84vLZY8oy1Xl34BodNzPN@BLxK@cpUgewY7MLHGW74WGnQhLlcAT/whQ2XFTownKlSL/by14uB3vpFzRkKhqVTCxnNaPUhiL3f5t4hiVSdSx3ofDFMHYFa5vYm/0coSiORGqIy9nuSoiluvUUaqFQex88KBoQ5/KBvQ/Hl/M1900UsCp1Yo8l7DbI9npHnTjHyfQIgggvsCTOWKZSEF6UPTdwzAIszlI2puIHVyIXShMKFBLyWxFiRxaWc@usrR8sE4PIYP09aZQSikSMWi6NjrM0ihTl8tbfNfiGEMP3svcTRbAiDjIPlTLwIk9JbIqWqgY/VOG/EYfYIa1frIz0LJd33yLygst7@IosUpd0ey@xUdWc8DJNlJ@zALYRvCWerNFkqSZ0OrNZL7U0sYTUU01IdU/G3FPOOac0Pj/raJWM7ro7w5OvGiQcSr3tkniJHgFsaRJIs7n@f1YyGZGUKNdQqzU2mpqNRuM/). Note that this won't work for every base since some numbers like `0xdc00` can't be converted to a character.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>210</s></sup> 200 bytes

```julia
_->0:19 .|>i->join(Int(c)÷95^i%95+' ' for i=0:2,c="膛㚥愹鳑선謈츀㰖嶼瞑廀")[20i.+(1:20)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NdLJUlpZAMbx/X0KRr1EZHBoEQXjiNi2AxHjFA2I6FW8IqJGDJYjgyKgiAg4QTkhAiqoIIOLPEoq3emqVNc5hwewk67q3bf4737f@KyGUPA/vaopIsrrULGYJ@RXUjifxUSxeHyKIHEpqceHWV@eKssHCWZleVEhpZCintJRCBFPWMIeFtHA43UEHphOoXnfCy48Aeg3J8C50/Td5IeXK1FoNbm@@s7hcjAEk1vLIGZz/Lmegns5PwrbbGA3G4Dmo2u48WDLW2988Cm3C4KpZ5iLOfLr9hA6NCVB@NYDc6dxtBZIgMPl@N/xHWSNOfP2RBA515Lg6DkBvOe7IL16hG6vAnn7iRWmb7fRhtkBM@EEcq14US4aRAGLC0Zdm@g4FgbumzDyeOwgcOcHFxEPWnM8g4zVB89vHqB74wleBfZBcPUFhT02FE55kTt8i5Ih14/1U@i4y4DQsQX4Lx/hhnsL@jNbKOFaRecXThT0BmAimUW25BNwb@2i0/Q93N8Mose9FxhNXH2/scDItQdkc6EfyWWY8yZA2HcCUocukN2Jwah1H24HjtGhbQeuuT3owu6FKy9PaNeyh9J7z19v94Ereg89D8d5R8IKIpls3u46g5GHF7QSt8J4eBVEdpIglrOAwOYzOrAmvz1m/jreAa6zZRiKbv5zfgEjlgzc2s6ClzsHSASP4YE5DN3XB3DVlfqWXoaelAc4HZcglTajW/8B2M3toUu7DxyuPILT@AncS/hRPGJC7rQThbJ2dBa6zjvdPnR/50POmI3G6i/hEZwinC8s4bE@vM6N6Ihfx9Ip5mk0GkabFHQbJaKGtxUSvqZWyp7jCT5idHysTcmrFXRRR6tEonfdCkn5EjZKG5c3UZWTsl68VPqWVNSUvFvE1C3dhimupLNXzlxQatXy6VKFBOs1KPrHh9nvWxjKjsEKnbGqQWHEuoupfUVtE8KPXO3UsFHF7RFKBrCZ9z2LKmWtfO43NvGBKZMwxmRajMVWqopquItyvl7eX1VdNctpm8D6mjqk7YYWbjMx2UolRz4NszUzWPMfzInSBgZZ8lnGFrTWFI5Ih0hseoYzYVASGoa8c2GI3sfS0Akm9kZSNqorqZYNLtC5RGclu7pIy8SMdb2ksnSoQEidrKIvdbby62v0mJojF89LJ7oMog6xUk2dnVdSVZgBZ@kkLPGScLqMPmBc0nY2zvVhovYuQVdZNVHOY3IFzJGeQVppI0b/fQYXGNsNfQUfZJ14cV3rQnUFpq2oW5I0zjQxWOIaBU2ll9TXF2LNVUKyQFvQhzNmJ9pU7EY9h9GONb2RT/MYqkn2JHNkvKNraZY93fqLCWv6SabGySn9GEGOsjBMqyNIvYbk4E2s/zf@sxFRZrQaQo//p8ym0AZIGov1@i8)

output is a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 147 chars

```
`"疘暹ᠶ脭ﭮ蹝ੇ㈭첃`Ck4β94τ33+C∑²
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%60%22%F1%96%98%8E%F3%89%9F%87%F3%92%B0%87%E7%96%98%F1%BF%9B%A4%F2%8D%83%A6%F0%9A%AA%9B%F3%A1%A8%85%F2%97%AD%87%F2%A5%99%B7%F0%9B%B3%9E%F3%AF%90%99%F3%83%AB%85%E6%9A%B9%F2%98%82%B4%F1%A9%91%A9%F1%98%94%BC%F3%88%80%92%F1%AC%B7%BF%E1%A0%B6%F1%B1%BD%91%F3%AB%A6%A0%F2%9E%9D%A3%F3%8C%B8%AA%F1%BF%9B%81%F3%A1%A5%AF%F1%82%8B%8B%F3%A1%8C%85%F2%B2%AF%9B%F1%B7%9A%97%F3%87%84%BB%F2%B1%8A%8F%F1%B3%A3%AC%F0%B0%AE%99%F2%BD%B2%8A%F1%8C%B4%AF%E8%84%AD%F1%B8%B5%B5%F3%9B%BF%92%F1%9B%BD%99%F0%9B%B4%AD%F2%BB%80%89%F3%A6%8F%9C%F2%AB%A6%9D%F2%97%BC%A8%F0%BF%B9%80%F2%B5%94%BE%F3%B1%84%A9%F2%8E%BA%BC%EF%AD%AE%F2%81%BB%9B%F2%A6%AA%B5%F2%B5%81%87%F1%AC%91%AC%F0%9B%B7%82%F3%86%AF%96%F2%81%9C%A3%F0%B0%B5%AD%F1%8C%85%95%F1%AC%8C%9C%F2%9D%A3%BA%F1%B6%9E%9C%F3%87%9B%B7%F1%89%9B%8D%F3%96%AD%BA%F1%96%93%BE%F1%81%AC%94%F1%AD%86%A4%F2%88%BA%A2%E8%B9%9D%F3%A9%BE%B6%F3%9C%9E%B2%F3%80%9E%86%F1%AA%9F%B4%F2%AD%99%9A%F0%9C%90%A7%F1%A7%A5%89%F2%8F%B5%93%F2%AA%A0%B2%F2%A9%91%9F%F2%A7%94%A3%F1%94%AA%A7%F2%90%A0%92%F2%A8%A9%BF%F3%98%AD%82%F3%A8%8A%85%F3%95%B9%B9%F3%8B%9A%88%F3%97%99%A7%F1%87%8A%A6%F0%91%95%9B%F3%80%A0%89%F0%93%AD%8D%E0%A9%87%F1%A5%A2%B4%F2%B0%BE%B7%F0%B8%B4%95%F3%96%86%96%F3%AB%BE%86%F2%81%AF%9E%F2%96%AA%85%F1%80%90%B0%F0%AC%8D%9B%E3%88%AD%F2%83%89%83%F1%9D%92%93%F2%90%99%B7%F2%A8%96%B4%F0%A7%98%B5%F1%91%8D%8F%F2%B1%B1%AE%F0%BD%BF%84%F1%9B%85%B9%EC%B2%83%F2%BE%BF%A5%F2%BB%9A%B3%F0%AE%83%B2%F2%BD%9E%97%F1%BC%99%84%F1%A5%BA%AE%F2%83%B6%9E%F2%BC%8E%8D%F2%8D%98%B0%F1%AD%94%BD%F2%B6%B8%8D%F1%9E%9F%A3%F0%94%9B%8E%F2%BA%9E%97%F2%A6%94%99%F1%A7%B0%A9%F1%AC%B4%87%60Ck4%CE%B294%CF%8433%2BC%E2%88%91%C2%B2&inputs=123&header=&footer=)

At least I think it's 130 chars - I had to count by hand...

Comment: This is 147 chars

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~, 4347 bytes

```
{i}{i}{i}iiiic{{i}ddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{i}{i}{i}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ddddc{d}c{i}dddcddddc{d}ic{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}ddc{{i}dddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{i}ddc{d}{d}{d}ic{{i}ddd}iiiic{{d}iii}c{i}ddc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}ii}ddddddc{i}{i}iiiiiciiiiic{{i}dddd}iiiic{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}c{{d}iiiii}c{i}{i}dddc{d}ic{i}{i}{i}ddc{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddd}c{{d}iiiiii}ddddciicc{i}{i}iiciiic{i}ic{d}{d}ddddddc{d}{d}iic{{i}ddd}iiic{{d}}{d}ddddddc{{i}d}iiic{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}iic{d}{d}dc{d}dddddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{{i}dddd}iiiiic{i}ic{d}{d}{d}iiic{i}dddc{{d}iiiii}ic{i}ic{i}{i}iic{d}ic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{d}dddc{d}{d}{d}ddddc{d}dddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{i}dddddd}c{{d}}{d}dddc{{i}d}iic{d}{d}{d}iic{i}iic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}dc{{d}iiii}ddddc{i}{i}iiiic{i}c{i}ddcddddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}dd}iiiic{d}{d}dddc{i}iiiic{d}c{d}{d}iiic{i}{i}{i}ddc{{d}iiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{d}{d}ddddddc{{d}iiii}dc{{i}dd}dc{i}{i}{i}iiic{d}{d}dddddcddddddc{i}iiiiic{d}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{d}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddd}iic{d}{d}iic{i}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddd}dc{i}ic{{d}iiii}ddddddc{i}dc{i}{i}{i}dc{i}{i}{i}ddc{{d}}{d}dddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dc{d}ddc{{i}dddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{i}{i}{i}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}dddd}iiiiicdc{d}ddc{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}dddddc{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}ic{d}{d}{d}c{i}iiic{i}{i}ic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}iicic{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}dddcddc{d}{d}{d}dddc{i}{i}c{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiii}ddddc{d}c{{i}dddd}ic{d}ddc{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{d}dc{d}{d}{d}dddddc{{i}ddd}ddc{d}{d}ddc{i}{i}{i}c{{d}}ddc{i}{i}{i}iciiic{{i}ddddd}iiiiciic{{d}iiii}iiic{i}{i}c{d}ddddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}iic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{{i}ddd}dddc{d}{d}{d}dciiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddcicdc{{i}dddd}ddc{{d}iii}dc{i}{i}{i}iic{i}{i}{i}dc{{d}}iiic{{i}dd}c{d}{d}c{i}c{d}iiiciiiiiic{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}iic{d}{d}{d}iiic{i}{i}iiiiic{i}{i}{i}iiiciiiic{d}{d}{d}dddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dd}dddc{d}ic{i}{i}dc{d}{d}dc{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}dddd}iiiic{i}dddc{{d}}dddddc{{i}dddd}iiciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}ddd}c{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{i}{i}dddc{d}{d}{d}ddc{{i}ddd}iiiic{{d}iiii}c{{i}ddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{i}iic{i}{i}c{d}dddc{d}{d}ddddc{{i}dddd}iic{d}{d}{d}iic{i}{i}iic{i}iiiiic{{d}}c{{i}}iiiciic{{d}iii}ic{{i}dddd}ic{i}iiiiic{d}{d}ddddc{i}dddciiic{{d}iii}ddc{{i}ddddd}dcddddc{{i}dddddd}c{d}{d}ddddddc{{d}iiii}c{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddd}dddc{{d}iii}dddc{{i}ddd}c{{d}iii}iic{d}{d}{d}iiic{i}{i}{i}iic{i}{i}{i}dc{d}{d}ic{{i}ddddd}ic{i}ic{{d}iiii}ddddc{i}c{i}{i}iic{i}iic{i}{i}{i}dddc{{d}ii}ddddddc{i}iic{{i}dddd}ddc{d}{d}ddddc{d}{d}ddddc{d}dddc{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}iiic{{i}ddd}dc{{d}iii}dddddc{d}{d}{d}iiic{{i}}{i}iiiiic{{d}iiii}ic{i}{i}iiic{i}{i}ic{d}ddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiii}iiic{i}{i}c{d}{d}dddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiii}c{d}{d}ddddc{{i}d}ic{{d}iiiiii}dddddcdddddc{d}{d}{d}iiic{i}{i}ddcddddc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}}ddddddc{{i}d}iic{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{d}{d}dddc{{i}dddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}dddc{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiii}dc{i}{i}dc{d}{d}iic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiiciiiic{{d}iii}ic{{i}dd}iiiiciic{d}{d}dc{{d}iiii}dddddc{{i}ddd}dddc{{d}i}c{{i}}{i}iic{{d}ii}ddcic{{i}ddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{d}{d}{d}c{i}{i}ic{{i}dddd}iiiic{{d}iii}iic{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiii}dc{d}{d}iiic{{i}dddd}dddc{i}{i}{i}iiicic{d}ddddc{d}{d}{d}dc{d}ddc{{i}ddddd}dc{d}{d}{d}iic{{d}ii}c{{i}ddddd}ic{i}{i}ddciiiiic{d}{d}{d}iic{i}{i}{i}ddc{d}{d}{d}ddc{i}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}ddcdddddc{d}dc{i}c{i}dc{d}{d}ic{{i}dddd}iiiic{d}dddciiiiiic{{d}iiii}c{i}{i}dddc{i}{i}ddc{{d}iiii}ic{i}{i}iiiiic{{i}dddddd}c{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iii}dddddc{i}iiiiiic{{i}ddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{d}{d}{d}ddc{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{d}dcdc{{d}iiiiii}dciiiiic{i}{i}ic{i}c{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiii}dcdddddc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}}iic{{d}iiii}iiic{i}ic{{i}dddd}c{{d}iiiii}dddddcddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{d}{d}{d}ddddciiiiic{i}{i}icic{i}{i}{i}iiiic{{d}iiii}dddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddcddddcc{d}{d}{d}iic{d}{d}{d}ic{{i}dddd}iic{d}dddcdc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iii}ddc{{i}ddd}iiiic{{d}iii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}cddddc{{i}dd}ic{d}c{d}{d}{d}ic{i}{i}iic{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{i}{i}iiiiic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iii}c{d}c{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iii}ic{{i}dddd}c{d}{d}{d}iic{{i}dddddd}iiic{i}{i}{i}ddc{{d}iiii}dddddc{d}ddc{{i}dddd}iiiic{i}dc{{d}iiii}dddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiic{{d}iii}ddc{{i}dddd}iiiiciiiiic{d}{d}ddddddciiiic{{i}dddddd}iic{d}ic{{d}iii}dddc{{i}ddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}iiic
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 100 + 140 bytes

```
,[<+++[>>++>+<<[->-[>+>>]>[[-<+>]+>+>>]<<<<<]>>,<[-<----[>>-<<----]>>-<]>.[-]<<<-[->>>+<<<]>>>]>>>,]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LVLbjqNGEJXy6F9hHAzGfZEcpJVHwTvNLiTMBl_khyYLw8WY7oJuA7-Sl3lJpHxS8h95T3uTkrpULZ26nFP1258Z8OpWqF-b9_ff1VAsyV9fn85by7LOvm9ZvrXdnpf-8uxbvn_xz-fl1vIv1rff9mEX338yiO3SmMlYbr9Fl0d08b8_Lx-opangPyo90P7jPV3-6_V_y_e_v_uHSDaoOE_1sXD1MflAIN_3Rd6_HW8ThPxOoHqrdFJLVs_G3ekx8K4xKwXWK525r3TDy9Jmju7AWQjEJNmkQVfkFZzCseXVTL32A-ig1DicG6wYRZxddYQA2etyE5zoKb0qg-9ZNl-zYCYo2Fc6Py2U3K9bJGsqp0OledOJZ-cG-UQzF5dxVOojjFfplvQkodYpKPnsAt5piiIqYqbbEOZyMzGKo8OijXMsWLh-O6UuDXkvi_SrOIVOiZKObNjdUBTAwlEwZVNp4WvBx-HlMLZYEQLKAR1F0oN12_GfFoZSrHTKwKvXkrufqAyUKCKvQ_MMYcSIV30WRQq99zoJhiaCpwRi5tWh7QqUvpCNpSodjT3C64XEsiKo7UWc_9JkN-eGIk5k23d2IMQRJtnlK4LyqdecNAKPikfa4H9Wxa7XTI89Sw1Fd9cWkVp0EI83xBGRwaBsXmuxd-oweCZgrSqdtiAOrob8hSL1RWlGmxDPneQlxem602arH2FUshIEs_1CFszSAGOfJTXdTFTr_N4cD_MgJKPgxuYMvGv4OmnWOiTcXcFOPMEPc_uCKgLRj2ZpdYXjlQwrajSzUKt5ezNn0fBqoB77ZCiQwQOnD_MdxWhfFtFcyte7zJBNeVAZSValF49vKGfkWGGjuRLwPC2EkB2ViSPtKBJsnsssUUQmsaEYSHEwE-8agpIB4nQwE62l2H0hGDkQR2P9sfvhj4z3OfL-BQ)

Explanation: every 3 ASCII characters are encoded in 4 bytes (1 character). Counting bytes from left to right:

- the least significant \$6\$ bits of each \$n\$-th ASCII char are stored in the least significant \$6\$ bits of the \$n+1\$-th byte of the Unicode char;
- the \$6\$-th least significant bit of each \$n\$-th ASCII char is stored in the \$n\$-th bit of the first byte of the Unicode char.

Visually:

```
0abcdefg 0hijklmn 0opqrstu => 11110oha 10bcdefg 10ijklmn 10pqrstu
```